# Moodle LTI, Tool Change score post communication

Tags: moodle, lti

Can the following scenario be achieved with Moodle - LTI ToolProvider:

1. User A launches Exam X on Moodle
2. Moodle connects to LTI and opens Exam X on Tool T
3. User A takes Exam X in new Window on Tool T and finishes Exam X.
4. Score 50 and GradingProgress.PendingManual is returned from Tool T to Moodle.
5. Corrector C Logs into Tool T, 2 Days later and assings extra points for question 2 of Exam X.
6. New Score 60 and GradingProgress.FullyGraded are returned by Tool T to Moodle.
7. Score and Status are updated on Moodle.

So my question is, is it possible that a Tool T can change the score and grading status of an Exam X for User A, after User A has taken the exam? In the scenario a corrector C is changing the result. How can the Tool authenticate the Corrector (Teacher in Moodle) so he can influence the score and grade of Exam X of one of his students on Moodle?

Or does GradingProgess.PendingManual only mean, that a teacher can only change the grade of exam X on Moodle itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this kind of workflow is definitely supported and all grading is done in the tool. Moodle won't record the score value at step 4, however, as it requires "GradeProgress" to match "FullyGraded" before the score is recorded (see [the relevant scores code](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/27cbb5965ea34dc142a519cfa72be8cdab353156/mod/lti/service/gradebookservices/classes/local/resources/scores.php#L202-L204)).

Additionally, the PendingManual status does not mean the instructor needs to change the grade in Moodle; the final grade can be recorded in the tool (step 5) and sent from the tool (step 6).

The instructor can launch into the tool one of several ways to make the grade update (step 5):

1. Via the normal Resource Link launch (i.e. launch the activity from Moodle), then proceed to view the submission and (re)grade the user.
2. Via a [Submission Review](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-sr/v1p0) launch from the Moodle gradebook. To do this, view the cell actions for a particular student/activity in the gradebook and select "Grade Analysis". Should the tool support this specification, this will launch into the relevant grading view within the tool, where the instructor can then update the grade for that student.

When the final score/grade is sent back with a "GradingProgress" value of "FullyGraded", then the score will be visible in the Moodle gradebook.